# A few questions about divs and css (stick to margins and problems with hover)

Tags: html, css

I'm new here, after 12 years and re-learning some code, just for fun and to learn some basics.

So I got stucked with a few things and can't find a real and a simple solution to not mess up the code.

Here's the code:

```css
header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #8a2be2;
    font-family: monospace;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #98e624;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #034203;
    position: static;
    margin: 0 ;
}
.medic {
    color:#478bca;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.medic:hover {
    color:red;
}
ul {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 1.2em 0.5em 1em 0.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li:hover{
    color:red;
    background-color: khaki;
}

a {
    color: #045e04;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css"> <!--El: type="text/css" no es necesario incluirlo-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css"> <!-- Este enlace es el de los iconos que te hablé de la web de Font Awesome-->

</head>
<title> Test 1 </title>
<body>
    <!--<main> // No es necesario-->
<!-- YA existe una etiqueta "Header" en HTML5, esto no lo necesitas <div id="header">-->
    <header>
    <h1> TEST 1 </h1>
    </header>
    <!--</div>--> 
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Contenido</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So what I want to do is really simple, on the top menu I just want a way to hover all the links only with the exact height of the div and at the same time I want the fontawesome icon to get hover when you drag the mouse over the links and not separately like my code shows, can't really find a way to do that. Also, I'm tryin to stick the "menu" div to the sides without any blank space, I've tried margin, position:absolute and sticky and negative padding but nothing seems to work, only position:absolute worked fine but if I do it that way then the next div won't appear... What am I doing wrong?

Thank you everyone!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear in a way that it is hard to understand what the code is suppost to do/look like. Could you clarify the desired output a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I corrected your code.

**:hover issue**

Please Select `<a>` and `<i>` tag and style a link when you mouse over it:

```
li:hover a, li:hover a i{
    color:red;
}
```

**Remove the spaces**

Please use `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;`

```
li{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Please Add `margin:0px;` on `<ul>` to remove by default margin.

```
ul {
    margin:0px;
  }
```

```css
html, body{margin: 0; padding:0px}

header {
    text-align: center;
    color: #8a2be2;
    font-family: monospace;
}
#menu {
    background-color: #98e624;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #034203;
    position: static;
    margin: 0 ;
}
.medic {
    color:#478bca;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.medic:hover {
    color:red;
}
ul {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center; margin:0px;
}

li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding:8px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

li:hover{
    color:red;
    background-color: khaki;
}
li:hover a, li:hover a i{
    color:red;
}

a {
    color: #045e04;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#content {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<body>
    <!--<main> // No es necesario-->
<!-- YA existe una etiqueta "Header" en HTML5, esto no lo necesitas <div id="header">-->
    <header>
    <h1> TEST 1 </h1>
    </header>
    <!--</div>--> 
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a link href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-md medic"></i>Menú 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Contenido</p>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Wow @Priya jain thank you really much, I'm so stupid... really appreciate the help but now I have two more questions...

One, when you fixed the code the "menu" seems to be a little heigher, maybe I should adjust the padding height?

And one more thing, about the right-left margins, it still shows me spaces on the sides, maybe margi left and right 0px will fix it?

Thank you again!!

Comment: One, you can set the height of the menu by updating padding of <li> tag as you want. Two, In most major browsers, the default margin is 8px on all sides. You can remove space on the sides by adding CSS 'html, body{margin: 0; padding:0px}'